# How to swap two UIWebViews in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiwebview

In my app I have a sliding view that holds UIWebView, that I want to substitute with another UIWebView that has already loaded content on user tap instead of loading the current view.

I tried just simply assign one view to another:

```
UIWebView* webView1 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UIWebView* webView2 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

webView1 = webView2; // didn't work
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to keep them both around, you could just hide the one that should go away:

```
[webView1.superview addSubview: webView2];
[webView1 setHidden: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[webView1.superview addSubview: webView2];
[webView1 removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: if I remove the first one from superview it's getting deallocated

Comment: You'll need an instance variable of webView1 (and webView2 if you plan to switch them out later on) somewhere in your class that creates the web views.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Get the whole HTML string of the webView2:

   NSString  *htmlString = [webView2 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];
2. Load this HTML string to webView1.